# get top view of the image - cv2 Python

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I got an image from google [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbTPP.jpg)

I need to get the top view of the walking path in image, I planned to use  `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)`

the image shape is [1920,1943]

In this, I got src coordinate points which is

top-left point - [393,1409]

top-right point - [641,1402]

bottom-left point - [773,1867]

bottom-right point - [1312,1823]

Here, I tried many points for `dst`, but still didn't get the perfect top view

How to choose the `dst` points, so that I get the top view of the path in the image

thanks

Comment: pick the corners of the 12x2 tile array (tiles are arrayed). figure some good "model" positions for those points. done.

Answer (score 0):

For choosing the points, you have to choose them in a way that englobes the pathway, check this [picture](https://pyimagesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/getperspective_transform_02.jpg) for a reference
[image]

After you can do some maths to calculate the dst shape. Since you have selected already the points from your src image, to calculate dst shape you would need to calculate de distance between the points

```
np.sqrt( (x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 )
```

Applying that formula between top-left and top-right you would get the width. Note that you will need the biggest width and the biggest height